# Incorrect 'for' loop results C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am a beginner at using C++ so I was wondering if someone would be able to help me out as I'm currently trying to print a 'for' loop. The 'alfa' loop is printing correctly but when that information is called upon by the 'sina' loop, only zeros are being printed in the console.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <new>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

const double convToRad = pi/180.0;

int main(){

    int INDEX = 91;
    double alfa[INDEX] {0};
    double sina[INDEX] {0};

for (int p = 90; p >= 0; p--){
     alfa[INDEX] = p*convToRad;
     //std::cout << alfa[INDEX] << std::endl;
 }

for (int e = 0; e <= 90; e++){
    sina[INDEX] = sin(alfa[INDEX]);
    std::cout << sina[INDEX] << std::endl;        //only prints 0's
 }

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: `alfa[INDEX] = ...`, `sina[INDEX] = ...` Don't think that's what you meant there.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `p` and `e` as the index instead?

Comment: INDEX = 91 but value of p is 90 and it keeps on decreasing. 
Condition for e<=90  so it never reaches 91
Logically, this would fail and there is no element at  alfa[91] and sin(0) is 0.

Comment: Code does not compile.

Comment: Change `pi` to `M_PI`

Comment: Note `double alfa[INDEX] {0};` where `INDEX` isn't a `const` or literal integer constant is not standard C++ and is only allowed by non-standard compiler extension that makes C99 *Variable Length Arrays* available in C++.

Comment: Please see this https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7xf71W and compare.

Answer (score 1):

Your are accessing wrong memory location.
INDEX=91;
You had typed INDEX instead of p and e in both the loops.
So accessing a single wrong location which may gives a junk value or crash the program.

Answer (score 1):

**A few notes:**

- Don't use magical numbers, use constants.
- Don't use the numbers in the array which are constant as you did.

**Try a simple fix:**

```
for (int p = 0; p < INDEX; p++) {
    // storing 90* stuff in first index, 89* in second and so on...
    alfa[p] = (90 - p) * convToRad;
    // std::cout << alfa[p] << std::endl;
}

for (int e = 0; e < INDEX; e++) {
    sina[e] = sin(alfa[e]);
    std::cout << sina[e] << std::endl;
}
```